# I am trying to figure out where the c is coming from inside the function

Tags: javascript, function

```
var x = 2;
var y = 8;


var a = function(b) {
  return function(c) { 
    var num = Math.abs(b);
    return x + y + Math.abs(b) + c; 
  }; 
};

var fn = a(x);
x = 4;
console.log(fn( Math.random() * 10) );
```

ive tried to console log a, b, c and i still cant wrap my head on what is happening here

Comment: `c` is the parameter to any function returned from `a` - eg `fn`. So in this example the result of `Math.random() * 10` will be `c`.

Comment: Small side note; `num` is unused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two functions, let's call them `a` and `anonymous`.

**`a` is this:**

```
var a = function(b) {
  /* do stuff */
};
```

Which is equivalent to

```
function a(b) {
  /* do stuff */
};
```

Now, **let's define function `anonymous`:**

```
function anonymous(c) { 
    var num = Math.abs(b);          // note that 'b' is pulled in from the parent's scope
    return x + y + Math.abs(b) + c; // note that 'x' and 'y' also pulled in from the parent's scope
};
```

In javascript, functions can be assigned to variables. That's exactly what your example code does with var `a`: sets it equal to function `a`.

Because of this ability to assign functions to variables, functions can actually return **other functions** as a value. This is also exactly what `a` does. It returns the function `anonymous`.

```
var a = function(b) {
  return anonymous;
};
```

Now, in your code, the function anonymous doesn't have a name. But, the `anonymous` that I defined is equal to the unnamed function that your `a` returns. Let's substitute it in for `anonymous` from the previous code block.

```
var a = function(b) {
  return function(c) { 
    var num = Math.abs(b);
    return x + y + Math.abs(b) + c; 
  }; 
};
```

You could equivalently write:

```
var a = function(b) {
  var anonymous = function(c) { 
    var num = Math.abs(b);
    return x + y + Math.abs(b) + c; 
  }; 
  return anonymous;
};
```

Thus, when you call `var fn = a(x)`, `fn = anonymous`, the function. Recall that anonymous takes in an argument, and it names that argument `c`.

Thus, when we call `fn(Math.random() * 10)`, fn is replaced with `anonymous` and since the argument to `anonymous` is `Math.random() * 10`, when `anonymous` executes, `c = Math.random() * 10`

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, this is my first explanation, it might be hard to understand but I'm trying my best to explain:

I just want to break out the code:

your code:

```
var x = 2;
var y = 8;


var a = function(b) {
  return function(c) { 
    var num = Math.abs(b);
    return x + y + Math.abs(b) + c; 
  }; 
};

var fn = a(x);
x = 4;
console.log(fn( Math.random() * 10) );
```

It is totally confusing to have

```
console.log(fn( Math.random() * 10) )

instead of that line of code, I changed it to 

console.log(fn(10) ) for simplitcity.
```

As you execute var fn = a(x), b value will be 2 and fn will be assigned to the return value of var a which is a function indeed

so here what fn becomes:

```
var fn = function(c) { 
    var num = Math.abs(b);
    return x + y + Math.abs(b) + c; 
  }; 
x = 4;// x value was changed to 4 instead of 2 from the line 1
```

now he is passing c value through the last line of code which is :

```
console.log(fn( Math.random() * 10) );

or 

for simplicity 
console.log(fn(10) );
```

so finally the code will be looking like this:

```
var y = 8;
var fn =  function(c) { 
    var num = Math.abs(b);
    return x + y + Math.abs(b) + c; 
  }; 
x = 4;
console.log(fn(10) );
```

Hopefully, you understood by my explanation.